# How to communicate through network in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an application where an administrator can logout an logged in user from administration interface, the user
who has been logged out needs to see an alert message that he has been logged out by adminstratior, once he clicks on the ok
button the application should log off.

U is an user logs in to a "X" wpf application in  172.0.0.1 machine

A is administrator logs the "X" wpf application  in 172.0.0.2 machine, he has an interface from where he can
see U is logged in. He Logs off him from that interface, Following are my thoughts on how to acheive it

1)We can insert a record into database when adminstrator log off the user & application need to continuosuly poll the database if 
log off message has been logged; if logged it will prompt the user. I am not finding this method as efficient.

2)We can use MSMQ, but I am not sure whether MSMQ is intended for such communication

3)We can create TCP sockets and send them from one end, and we can receive it in another end and log off the user

What is the correct approach? Is there anyway that sql server can start communicating to wpf application when some data has 
been inserted using IP Address?

I have find a similar question in stack overflow, but the answer link is not redirecting to the correct resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this approach.

When a user logs in, log his ip address in a database table.
Have the user application listen UDP or TCP it does not really matter on a port
When the administrator wants to log him of, then he sends to that ip address and the same port.
When the user logs of, he removes himself from the table.

this way there is no polling.